# Can i make following code any Faster

Tags: java, performance

I would like to make the following code faster, without changing the reading/writing from standard console. The first line contains the number of inputs and the subsequent lines contain a set of `Integer`s.

```java
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        try {
            java.io.BufferedReader r = new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(System.in));
            int a = Integer.parseInt(r.readLine());
            for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
                StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(r.readLine());
                while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                    int first = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                    int second = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                    if (first < second)
                        System.out.println("<");
                    else if (first > second)
                        System.out.println(">");
                    else
                        System.out.println("=");
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.print(e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You can try to use a [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html), but I'm not sure that it will be faster.

Comment: First of all: write good code. After that, look into efficiëncy. Don't use StringTokenizer. It has been deprecated for several versions of Java, and replaced by the split method of String. to quote the StringTokenizer api: StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead.

Comment: Scanner is slower than  StringTokenizer. i am submitting it in codechef .

Comment: your code have a lot of syntax error. `else` inside `for` without `if`?

Comment: It will go faster if you can compile it.

Comment: sorry about that . somehow code changed .

Comment: @somaniA: StringTokenizer is not recommended to use in either case.

Answer (score 0):

You are performing a lot of redundant autoboxing and outboxing there which could be saved if you define `first` and `second` as primitive `int`s instead of `java.lang.Integer` wrapper classes. I doubt, however, that for any reasonable size of input you'd even notice the difference.

Comment: thanks i have changed it . what else can i do here ?

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few suggestions, I am not sure these will help a lot.

1) This,

```
                if (first < second)
                    System.out.println("<");
                else if (first > second)
                    System.out.println(">");
                else
                    System.out.println("=");
```

can be changed to

```
                    System.out.println(first < second
                                       ? "<"
                                       : first > second
                                         ? ">"
                                         : "="
                                      );
```

2) Since you are using a throws clause and your `try-catch` does nothing you can remove it.

3) Here,

```
                int first = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                int second = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
```

You are not checking for `hasMoreTokens()` the second time.

4) Use `split()` instead of `StringTokenizer`. More on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 0):

You may consider to use the `BufferedReader`'s constructor below:

```
public BufferedReader(Reader in, int sz)
```

Giving the `sz` parameter *a reasonable high value*, can avoid the buffer to be refilled too often.

---

As a side note, while `readLine()` retuns `null` if the end of the stream has been reached, it's better to check its return value before calling `new StringTokenizer(r.readLine())` and `Integer.parseInt(r.readLine())`.
The edited class follows:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedReader r;
        String line;
        StringTokenizer st;
        int a, first, second;

        r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in), 4096);
        try {
            line = r.readLine();
            if (line != null) {
                a = Integer.parseInt(line);
                for (int i = 0; i < a; ++i) {
                    line = r.readLine();
                    if (line == null)
                        break;
                    st = new StringTokenizer(line);
                    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                        first = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                        second = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                        if (first < second)
                            System.out.println("<");
                        else if (first > second)
                            System.out.println(">");
                        else
                            System.out.println("=");
                    }
                }
            }
            r.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.print(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```